# create navigationdrawer and call previous activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-listfragment

I have a running app with many activity. Currently i have  buttons and onclick event related activity get open. Now i have created a new navigationdrawer activity [provided by android eclipse] and listed all button options in the drawer list menu. Now i want to call my activities onclick of the list menu selection. I have tried and find out many solution but failed to implement.

Is any one let me know in which function i have write code to call my activity? Is it onSectionAttached() if its so then how? when i have tried with Intent.. and start avtivity the new activity get loaded and Navigation drawer get disable.

Do i have to create new fragments classes?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two options. You can use an intent and then implement a drawer in the second activity. Not ideal because this leads to a lot of code duplication.

OR (better)

You can use another layout for your activity. Something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then you can use fragments in the framelayout. Then just use fragmentmanager and replace the fragment in the frame for the one the user clicks on in the drawer.

Check out http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html for more info.